# X frame option Deny Alternative

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, iframe, websecurity

I have added a setting that my project URL will never be loaded in an iframe by adding a header

> response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "deny");

this is working fine but on the Iframe page , i just see a broken image saying refuse to connect with URL. Is it possible if i want to show some specific message with this kind of request or the URL will automatically open in a separate tab rather then the Iframe as we don't wan't customer to view this look and feel.

Comment: I believe that there is no standardized way to do this, but you could redirect to another page with message if request is not from same origin, that will produce very similar effect to what you want. Because you are trying to prevent clickjacking I believe.